# Make changes of colors of icons visible in openlayers with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, openlayers

I try to accomplish that I will be able to change the color of marker icons to be visible in the map. They are in the map in different colors. Those colors are correspondenting to the json cat_id key's.

```
1: "http://dev.openlayers.org/img/marker.png",
2: "http://dev.openlayers.org/img/marker-blue.png",
3: "http://dev.openlayers.org/img/marker-gold.png",
4: "http://dev.openlayers.org/img/marker-green.png",
```

Each marker icon that is in the map is getting it's position, color and other valuable data from the json objects in the data id in the script tag. I didn't code the part of that work's close with the openlayer libary's. I wrote the following part of the total of the script:

```
var json = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;
json = JSON.parse(json); // converts text into JSON

// search criteria (could be changed)
var $search_postal = "8912JB";
var $search_number = "10";
var $change_cat = 1;

function changeColor() {
    for (var key in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (json[key].postal == $search_postal) {
                if (json[key].number == $search_number) {
                    alert("Gonna change cat_id " + json[key].cat_id + " of the number search string " + $search_number + " of the postal search string " + $search_postal + " to cat_id " + $change_cat);
                    json[key].cat_id = "1";
                    alert('Changed!');
                    const posts = json; // the constant that is used to display the icons
                    var myJSON = json;
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myJSON, undefined, 2); // changes of the json data to see on screen
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

const posts = json; //the constant that is used to display the icons

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(json);
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myJSON;
```

This script will change the cat_id of the given search input. In the example it does a search for postal 8912JB with number 1. Once it has made the loop to find it's position it will change the cat_id value of 3 to 1. In other words the json data has been changed. Since it is stored in the const posts I replace this cons with the changed data. My problem is that I'm unable to refresh the marker icon(s) in the map with the new json data that is changed (cat_id: 1 of postal 8912JB number 10). This has to do with less knowledge about openlayers and Javascript. I'm struggling already 2 weeks with this. Can anybody help me to accomplish this? If it changes from color is the only thing that is required. I would only need to give the changes to the variables $search_postal, $search_number and $change_cat.

Here is the page for debug: https://jsfiddle.net/j4z1vpht/4/

Thanks for any help,

grid

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the new category to the map feature, like this:

```
const updateFeatureCategory = (featureId, categoryId) => {
  const feature = marker_layer.getSource().getFeatureById(featureId);
  const post = feature.get("post");
  const updatedPost = {
    ...post,
    cat_id: categoryId
  }
  feature.set("post", updatedPost);
}
```

```
function changeColor() {
  ...
  json[key].cat_id = "1";
  updateFeatureCategory(key, "1");
  ...
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wsm2h3qz/1/